# Simple case of string mutation

Tags: c

I need help with this very simple case of string mutation to understand how string mutations work:

structure "id" is defined as:

```
  struct id {char digits[11];};
```

Write a method AtoB that has 2 parameters *a and *b and it sets the value of *b to *a:

Since string is an array of character, the following code does not work:

```
void AtoB (struct id *a,struct id *b) {
(*b).digits = (*a).digits;}
```

However, it does not necessarily behave the same way as an array does, so how to do it? Also as a beginner student, I'm only allowed to use the most basic code in c.

Comment: you code won't compile. you have to move it byte by byte

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: or assign the whole structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign an array to an array in C. But you can assign structure objects:

```
void AtoB (const struct id *a, struct id *b)
{
    *b = *a;
}
```

(Be sure to remove the `const` in the `b` parameter declaration otherwise it means `*b` object cannot be modified through the means of `b`.)

**EDIT:** the question has now been edited and now no `const` appears in the parameters declaration.